# Why is a C# finally block causing an extra method call?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, jit

I was looking at the generated assembly code when creating a small tracer class which should be as fast as possible. The idea is to create wrapper class which traces method enter on leave and when the method is left a method leave trace. That can be achieved with using statements

```
public void DoStruct()
{
    using var tmp = Wrapper.Create(nameof(DoStruct));
}
```

That will create a struct Tracer instance which is disposed on method leave automatically. So far so good. Now lets look at the generate assembly:

```
NetCoreJitStruct.User.DoStruct()
Begin 00007FFC91651860, size 61
00007ffc`91651860 push    rbp
00007ffc`91651861 sub     rsp,30h
00007ffc`91651865 lea     rbp,[rsp+30h]
00007ffc`9165186a xor     eax,eax
00007ffc`9165186c mov     qword ptr [rbp-8],rax
00007ffc`91651870 mov     qword ptr [rbp-10h],rsp
00007ffc`91651874 mov     qword ptr [rbp+10h],rcx
00007ffc`91651878 mov rcx,268F07F30D8h
00007ffc`91651882 mov     rcx,qword ptr [rcx]
00007ffc`91651885 call    00007ffc`91650800 (NetCoreJitStruct.Wrapper.Create(System.String) *** Ctor called
00007ffc`9165188a mov     qword ptr [rbp-8],rax
00007ffc`9165188e jmp     00007ffc`91651890
00007ffc`91651890 mov     rcx,rsp
00007ffc`91651893 call    00007ffc`9165189f (NetCoreJitStruct.User.DoClass() *** Dispose Called via extra method Call!
00007ffc`91651898 nop
00007ffc`91651899 lea     rsp,[rbp]
00007ffc`9165189d pop     rbp
00007ffc`9165189e ret
    00007ffc`9165189f push    rbp  ** Dispose wrapper method
    00007ffc`916518a0 sub     rsp,30h
    00007ffc`916518a4 mov     rbp,qword ptr [rcx+20h]
    00007ffc`916518a8 mov     qword ptr [rsp+20h],rbp
    00007ffc`916518ad lea     rbp,[rbp+30h]
    00007ffc`916518b1 lea     rcx,[rbp-8]
    00007ffc`916518b5 call    00007ffc`91650818 (NetCoreJitStruct.Wrapper.Dispose()
    00007ffc`916518ba nop
    00007ffc`916518bb add     rsp,30h
    00007ffc`916518bf pop     rbp
    00007ffc`916518c0 ret
```

What I do not understand is why is the JIT compiler is factoring the dispose method call into an extra wrapper method. The behavior is the same for .NET 4.8 + some more inefficient code gen.
I have checked if that is an issue with struct method inlining but the behavior is the same for classes which are disposed.

Is this the fastest I can get with .NET or do I miss some pattern to make it faster/more JIT friendly?

Compiler: C# 7+ 
.NET: .NET 4.8 or .NET Core 3.1

Below is the full source code

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace NetCoreJitStruct
{
    class Program
    {

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Queue<string> argList = new Queue<string>(args);
        bool useStruct = true;
        bool nofactory = false;
        bool nop = false;
        bool direct = false;

        while (argList.Count > 0)
        {
            string arg = argList.Dequeue().ToLower();
            switch (arg)
            {
                case "-trace":
                    CustomData.IsEnabled = true;
                    break;
                case "-struct":
                    break;
                case "-class":
                    useStruct = false;
                    break;
                case "-direct":
                    direct = true;
                    break;
                case "-nop":
                    nop = true;
                    break;
                case "-nofactory":
                    nofactory = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("NtCoreJitStruct [-trace] [-struct or -class]");
                    return;
            }
        }

        var user = new User();
        user.DoClass_Factory();
        user.DoStruct_Factory();
        user.DoStructTryFinally();
        user.DoStructNoFinally_Factory();
        user.DoStructNoFinally_NoFactory();

        const int Runs = 1500_000_000;
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        if (nop) // measure loop overhead
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Runs; i++)
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (useStruct)
            {
                if (direct)
                {
                    if (nofactory)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Runs; i++)
                        {
                            user.DoStructNoFinally_NoFactory();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Runs; i++)
                        {
                            user.DoStructNoFinally_Factory();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (nofactory)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Runs; i++)
                        {
                            user.DoStruct_NoFactory();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Runs; i++)
                        {
                            user.DoStruct_Factory();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Runs; i++)
                {
                    user.DoClass_Factory();
                }
            }
        }

        sw.Stop();
        string scenario = useStruct ? "Struct" : "Class";
        Console.WriteLine($"Scenario: {scenario} NoFactory: {nofactory} Nop: {nop} Direct: {direct} Did execute {Runs:N0} Trace calls in {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds:F0} ms");
    }
}


class User
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public void DoClass_Factory()
    {
        using var tmp = CWrapper.Create(nameof(DoClass_Factory));
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public void DoStruct_Factory()
    {
        using var tmp = Wrapper.Create(nameof(DoStruct_Factory));
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public void DoStructTryFinally()
    {
        var tmp = Wrapper.Create(nameof(DoStruct_Factory));
        try
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            tmp.Dispose();
        }
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public void DoStructNoFinally_Factory()
    {
        var tmp = Wrapper.Create(nameof(DoStruct_Factory));
        tmp.Dispose();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public void DoStructNoFinally_NoFactory()
    {
        var tmp = new Wrapper(nameof(DoStruct_Factory));
        tmp.Dispose();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    internal void DoStruct_NoFactory()
    {
        using var tmp = new Wrapper(nameof(DoStruct_NoFactory));
    }
}
public struct Wrapper : IDisposable
{
    CustomData data_;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static Wrapper Create(string input)
    {
        return CustomData.IsEnabled ? new Wrapper(input) : default;
    }

    public Wrapper(string a)
    {
        data_ = CustomData.IsEnabled ? new CustomData(a) : null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (data_ != null)
        {
            data_.Dispose();
        }

    }
}

public class CWrapper : IDisposable
{
    CustomData data_;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static CWrapper Create(string input)
    {
        return CustomData.IsEnabled ?  new CWrapper(input) : default;
    }

    public CWrapper(string a)
    {
        data_ = CustomData.IsEnabled ? new CustomData(a) : null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (data_ != null)
        {
            data_.Dispose();
        }

    }
}

class CustomData : IDisposable
{
    public static bool IsEnabled;

    string myData;

    public CustomData(string data)
    {
        myData = data;
        Console.WriteLine("Entered method {0}", data);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Left method {0}", myData);
    }
}
```

}

Some Test Results:

```
JitStruct.exe -nop
Scenario: Struct NoFactory: False Nop: True Direct: False Did execute 1,500,000,000 Trace calls in 404 ms

JitStruct.exe -struct
Scenario: Struct NoFactory: False Nop: False Direct: False Did execute 1,500,000,000 Trace calls in 4837 ms

JitStruct.exe -struct
Scenario: Struct NoFactory: False Nop: False Direct: False Did execute 1,500,000,000 Trace calls in 4832 ms

JitStruct.exe -struct -direct
Scenario: Struct NoFactory: False Nop: False Direct: True Did execute 1,500,000,000 Trace calls in 4146 ms

JitStruct.exe -struct -direct
Scenario: Struct NoFactory: False Nop: False Direct: True Did execute 1,500,000,000 Trace calls in 4156 ms

JitStruct.exe -struct -direct -nofactory
Scenario: Struct NoFactory: True Nop: False Direct: True Did execute 1,500,000,000 Trace calls in 6424 ms

JitStruct.exe -struct -direct -nofactory
Scenario: Struct NoFactory: True Nop: False Direct: True Did execute 1,500,000,000 Trace calls in 6389 ms

JitStruct.exe -struct -direct -nofactory
Scenario: Struct NoFactory: True Nop: False Direct: True Did execute 1,500,000,000 Trace calls in 6417 ms

JitStruct.exe -struct  -nofactory
Scenario: Struct NoFactory: True Nop: False Direct: False Did execute 1,500,000,000 Trace calls in 6063 ms
```

Comment: Are you quite certain that the Dispose wrapper method is causing you performance problems?

Comment: That's not a wrapper method but a [funclet](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/clr-abi.md#funclets). There is such a thing as [finally cloning](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/finally-optimizations.md#finally-cloning) that should optimize simple scenarios, but I will not pretend to understand when this does or does not kick in.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: By counting the superflous instructions: Yes. You can try it by calling DoStructNoFinally which generates the code I would expect.

Comment: *Have you run a profiler on this code and identified this to be an actual performance problem that runs afoul of one of your non-functional software requirements?*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes. I have some trace heavy code which is performance sensitive because it is using tracing a lot. If tracing would be faster I could instrument more hot code paths with tracing without much impact. Your question about if it is a problem is a bit misleading since I can always add so much tracing to my code that it will dominate CPU cost. The real question is how much of my code can I instrument with tracing without paying too much CPU for tracing when it is off. Tracing can therefore never be fast enough by that definition.

Comment: If you need super-fast tracing, another path to consider is profiling or instrumenting methods through something like PostSharp (or other ways of modifying IL). This has a steeper learning curve than plugging in a struct like this, but on the plus side you can tune the overhead to the absolute minimum required.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: This is not an option. Postsharp weaves the code in a post processing step into the code where it uses which code? I think it will be pretty much similar to the one above. IL weaving makes things not faster it just obfuscates what is executed when you get a crash dump and you crash in code that is not visible in the source file ... Profiling has similar issues and it is generic. You cannot add trace.Info(....) messages describing what the method was up to. Besides this it is much harder to setup.

Comment: Sure -- but IL rewriting *would* allow you to put the trace calls by replacing every `ret`, eliminating this extra call you have for `finally`. Unless having the exit trace even on an exception is desired, but then you probably have no choice but to take the funclet call hit. You did ask for the fastest you could get, not what was easiest...

Comment: @JeroenMoster: Yep exception tracing is also on the list which it supports.

Comment: Since the funclet is necessary for correct exception stack unwinding, the code you're seeing now is probably the best the JIT can do as long as a `finally` is needed. Unless one of the people who worked on this can pipe up and figure out if `finally` cloning can help (and if so, how to trigger that) but you have a better chance of waking up one of those through the repo (either with an issue or on Gitter).

Answer (score 0):

what you are seeing is the cost of branching, if you remove the if and try with, the  struct then change the code and try with the class you will see a huge difference in the runtime

you can also swap the if / else and you will mostly get the reverse of what you currently get

duplicate the for, one for the struct and one for the class, you will have another kind of result

---

clarification;

the for loop,

try with, then compile, run

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Runs; i++)
        {
            user.DoStruct();
        }
```

then try, compile, run

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Runs; i++)
        {
            user.DoClass();
        }
```

you will get different result.

I know my answer doesnt match the title, but I'm answering the first line of the post.

Comment: `you will see a huge difference in the runtime` -- I really doubt that.  Disposal is a non-trivial operation for most objects that implement it.  Whatever you're describing in your first paragraph (I don't really understand what you said) is unlikely to make any difference at all.

Comment: @fredou: Can you give a code example what exactly you mean? I have tried a factory method to get faster but interestingly only microbenchmarks did profit from it. Real trace using code did get slower. There seem many conflicting optimizations going on.

Comment: @Robertharvey: I have added the for loop separately for each scenario. The numbers are now much closer but still there is some difference. Measuring things is hard because when doing this with Benchmark.Net the factory method did show a clear win but actual use cases with more complex code did degrade quite a lot.